# Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 Server on my Android Phone?

Tags: 14.04, server, android, phone

Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 Server on my standard, run of the mill, arm based Android Phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arm build with GUI is no longer supported as a deployment platform as far as I am aware.  Something like Debian kit that uses overlay-file systems is probably your best option for using Ubuntu or Debian on a rooted device as a secondary operating system -- almost.